# MySql update query with OR

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this table that stores purchases and I made my site to add free trial to user for 3 days when they register.

I got cron job that runs every 24 hours, but there comes problem if user purchases while he got active trial.

My query:

```
UPDATE subscriptions SET days = days - 1 WHERE days > 0 AND (package="1month" OR package="3month" OR package="trial")
```

So, if user got active trial and active 1 month membership, this query will update hes trial and 1 month subscription, it should update only one subscription at the time.

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74fb6/1

How I can do it?

Comment: So if a user with an active trial pays a monthly subscription, you generate a second subscription record for the same  user_id ? Why don't make the user_id an unique key, and update the package and days fields when they pay?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said `it should update only one subscription at the time`, you should check with `UID` along with `package` in your table (though currently `UID` doesn't look like unique column, which it should be)

```
UPDATE subscriptions 
SET days = days - 1 
WHERE days > 0 
AND 
package = "1month"
AND
UID = 1
```